# What is the right verb to use with the word "marks"

Tags: phrase-request

Is it right to describe that I knew my exams results like this:

> My marks had showed up / had been announced

Or is there a better way?

Comment: Try either showed up or had shown up, but not had showed up. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20850/show-shown-and-showed

Comment: In the U.S., I think the word _grades_ is used more than _marks_, as in: _Our grades were announced Monday._

Comment: Your marks? The  person you are targeting in a scam? Did they arrive in the bar where you were having a drink?

Answer (score 4):

The phrasal verb "to show up" has several meanings: It can mean to embarrass someone by comparing their faults: "John showed me up by beating me in the race". Or to arrive at a place "He showed up late to the party", or to be found "Keep looking, your pen will show up eventually."

None of these meanings would seem to fit with getting your exam marks. So "My marks had been announced" is better. But why use the past perfect? "My marks were announced" is likely to be better.

You could also say the the marks were "released" or "published". Or change the subject to focus on the person "I received my marks" or "My teacher gave me my marks".

Comment: I see , actually I didn't think about changing the subject, do you think it's better than using "released" or "published" ?

Comment: Its different. Not better or worse, just another way of saying the same thing.  Think of your own language.